# How do i pass a google_gmail1::Gmail<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>> to a thread spawn?

Tags: multithreading, rust, threadpool, gmail-api

Very much new to Rust... I am looking to download email attachments from Gmail using a specified query, I have a rough synchronous code that functions and i am looking to use multi threading using ?Tokio::spawn? (since the rest of the project is already using tokio) the current multi-threaded? code is as follows:

```
struct EmailInterface {
    pub gmail: Gmail<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>>,
}

impl EmailInterface {
    async fn new(path_to_key: String) -> Result<EmailInterface, Box<dyn error::Error>> {
        let authenticator =
            ServiceAccountAuthenticator::builder(read_service_account_key(path_to_key).await?)
                .build()
                .await?;

        let gmail = Gmail::new(
            hyper::Client::builder().build(
                hyper_rustls::HttpsConnectorBuilder::new()
                    .with_native_roots()
                    .https_or_http()
                    .enable_http1()
                    .enable_http2()
                    .build(),
            ),
            authenticator,
        );

        Ok(EmailInterface { gmail })
    }

    pub async fn get_attachments(
        self,
        query: &str,
    ) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        if let Some(messages_list) = self
            .gmail
            .users()
            .messages_list("me")
            .q(query)
            .include_spam_trash(false)
            .doit()
            .await?
            .1
            .messages
        {
            let messages_id_list: Vec<String> = messages_list
                .into_iter()
                .flat_map(|message| message.id)
                .collect();

            for id in messages_id_list {
                tokio::spawn(async move {

                    let message = self.gmail
                        .users()
                        .messages_get("me", id.as_str())
                        .doit()
                        .await
                        .unwrap_or_default()
                        .1;

                    let message = self
                        .gmail
                        .users()
                        .messages_get("me", id.as_str())
                        .doit()
                        .await
                        .unwrap_or_default()
                        .1;
                    for part in message.payload {
                        if let Some(part_body) = part.body {
                            if let Some(attachment_id) = part_body.attachment_id {
                                let attachment = self
                                    .gmail
                                    .users()
                                    .messages_attachments_get(
                                        "me",
                                        id.as_str(),
                                        attachment_id.as_str(),
                                    )
                                    .doit()
                                    .await
                                    .unwrap_or_default();
                                let data = general_purpose::STANDARD
                                    .decode(&attachment.1.data.unwrap_or_default())
                                    .unwrap();
                                std::fs::write(part.filename.expect("Should have a name"), &data)
                                    .unwrap();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

the error i am currently getting

```
use of moved value: `self.gmail`
move occurs because `self.gmail` has type `Gmail<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

heck if there is a more streamlined way of doing this, I'm all ears (eyes?)

i have also tried using the ThreadPool crate & ChatGPT for suggestions but the latter always ends in error.

Comment: What crates are you using? Can you include cargo.toml ?

Comment: @harmic Likely `google-gmail1 = "4.0.1"` and `tokio = { version = "1.25.0", features = ["full"] }`, but I can't figure out where `general_purpose` is from.

Comment: general_purpose is from base64 engine

Comment: use base64::{engine::general_purpose, Engine as _};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*grumble grumble* [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *grumble*

First, one recommendation I give nearly every rust beginner on SO: Don't rely on your IDE for good error messages. Read the output of `cargo check`/`cargo watch`, it is often so much more informative and helpful:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `self.gmail`
  --> src/main.rs:52:41
   |
52 |                    tokio::spawn(async move {
   |   _________________________________________^
53 |  |                     let message = self
   |  |___________________________________-
54 | ||                         .gmail
   | ||______________________________- use occurs due to use in generator
55 |  |                         .users()
...   |
91 |  |                     }
92 |  |                 });
   |  |_________________^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because `self.gmail` has type `Gmail<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

In this case, it's telling you that it needs multiple `self.gmail`, because there's a for loop, but it only has one. What you need to know to avoid that is that if something doesn't implement `Copy`, it often still implements `Clone`. The difference is that the compiler is free to use `Copy` on its own to avoid moves, but you need to use `Clone` manually. In this case, you can use `Clone` to make a dedicated instance of the `gmail` client for each spawned future.

```rust
for id in messages_id_list {
    let gmail = self.gmail.clone();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let message = gmail
            .users()
            .…
        // replace all the other instances of self.gmail as well
```

This will make your code compile, but it won't work yet: [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) starts the tasks, but it doesn't ensure that they finish before your program exits:

> There is no guarantee that a spawned task will execute to completion. When a runtime is shutdown, all outstanding tasks are dropped, regardless of the lifecycle of that task.

The "runtime" here is what you created when you annotated `#[tokio::main]`, and its shutdown will happen when your `main` function exits.

Also, if you have a lot of mail, I suspect that gmail will be mad at you for hitting it with thousands of requests at the same time.

To fix both of these at once:

```rust
use futures::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt};

futures::stream::iter(&messages_id_list)
    .map(|id| async {
        let message = self
            .gmail
            .users()
        // …
        Ok::<_, String>(()) // You don't have error handling yet, so I'll use String as a dummy type.
    })
    .buffer_unordered(8)
    .try_collect::<()>()
    .await?;
```

The `buffer_unordered` part makes sure that maximally a fixed number of message getters run, and the `await` ensures that it all finishes before the `await` on `get_attachments` finishes. Note how there's also no need to `clone()` or `move` anymore, because Rust now knows that `self` will outlive the message getters, so you can just borrow `self` from there.

Lastly: I'd consider `async` one of the less nice parts of Rust to use. You picked something difficult to start with.

Comment: Regarding the async comment: it's definitely still a work in progress, so there are surprising limitations popping left and right for beginners.

Comment: I will give the second suggestion a go. and report back.

Comment: Thank you @Caesar, the  futures::stream suggestion works nicely, i will have to look more into this. Much appreciated,